# Non-working example in "Learn Python the Hard Way" by Zed Shaw

Tags: python, python-2.7

Ok, I'm trying to learn Python with "Learn Python the Hard Way" book by Zed Shaw and everything seems fine until the [Exercise 47](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex47.html). There is a couple of very misleading notions in this exercise and the previous one. In previous exercise we were told to apply the following structure to our projects (here is how it looks in ex47.py):

```
./bin:
__init__.py __init__.pyc

./docs:

./ex47:
__init__.py __init__.pyc    game.py     game.pyc

./tests:
__init__.py __init__.pyc    ex47_tests.py   ex47_tests.pyc
```

In previous exercise Zed told us to put some script in bin and modules to the folder, named after the project. I don't understand how exactly the script differs from the module, but OK. In exercise ex47 we are running automated tests with nosetests and they run OK from the root directory of the project, however Zed says that we should see:

```
$ python ex47.py
```

And this is not what I see. I see something like number of tests run, time and etc. Moreover I can't run the project with ex47.py from the root since there is no such file and there shouldn't be according to Zed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "what you should see" makes very little sense, and is likely an editing mistake. Pay attention instead to the textual explanations (such as they are) and the goal of the exercise as a whole. Essentially, what you're looking for is output that says all the tests passed - see especially that the next suggestion is to deliberately cause one of them to fail, so that you can see the difference in output.

If you can differentiate between "all tests passed" and "at least one test failed" (and pin point which test did), then you have completed the essential point of the exercise.

Comment: Ok, the problem is that I do see the output for tests and they all seem to pass, I was just a little bit mixed up with the what you should see section.